# How to calculator the ROI of Masternode

Tags: json, api, security, cryptography, httpresponse

I will show the Roi of each masternodes.
I used the [API](https://coinmarketcap.com/api/) provided from [coinmarketcap.com](https://coinmarketcap.com).
Many API provides the info such as price and market cap as well.
But it seems that it doesn't support the ROI.
How can I get the value?

Comment: Hi, everyone~ Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

```
Per day = (n/t) * r * b * a

ROI (return on investment, in year) = ((n/t) * r * b * a * 365)/1000,
```

where

- n - the number of personal active masternode
- t - the total number of masternodes)
- r - the current block reward
- b - blocks in an average day
- a - the average payment

From https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=3088389.msg%msg_id%